# How to debug Apache2 virtual hosts

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I'm hosting two websites in one server. Each has their own VirtualHost defined. First site works nicely but when I try to access the second I get redirected to the first one. It's like Apache would not recognize the correct VirtualHost by the ServerName and redirects me to the default (first) site.

Is there a log or something where I can see what steps Apache is taking when it handles my request? Does it log anywhere what ServerName it is using when it tries to find a matching VirtualHost?

Update:

I added a VirtualHost section for a subdomain of my second site and that works. It renders page from the correct application server that runs in 8501 port when I enter "interface.domain.com" into my browser. But when I try "www.domain.com" it redirects to my first site.

Below is my virtual host file for the second site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/domain/current/public

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8501/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName interface.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/domain/current/public

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8501/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2ctl -S

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 1.2.3.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
1.2.3.4:443        www.domainfirst.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/https_www_domainfirst_com.conf:1)
1.2.3.4:80         is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domainfirst.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domainfirst_com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domainfirst.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domainfirst_com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.domainfirst.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www_domainfirst_com.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain_com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain_com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www_domain_com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost interface.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www_domain_com.conf:10)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Solution:

Clear the browser cache. My browser had cached a rule to forward request to the other site.

Comment: Start with the output of `apachectl -S` and add it to your post if the problem is not immediately obvious.

Comment: You can create seperate logfiles for your vhosts, e.g.: `CustomLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-error.log`

Comment: @Unbeliever I added the apache2ctl -S output.

Comment: @Lenniey Which VirtualHost section I should put that custom log file declaration? To the domain.com or the domainfirst.com? I guess the later because the domain.com VirtualHost section is the one apache is not finding.

Comment: Just add it to every vhost with different logfile names. Then you can see what happens to every host.

Comment: Also (maybe) important: do you access your vhosts from your internal network or from the internet?

Comment: @Lenniey I access them through internet. I added the custom log files but as I suspected only one of them got any lines, the access log for domainfirst.com. By the time it logs to those files apache has already decided which virtualhost it uses for this request. I would need to get a log that includes the part where apache is making decision which virtualhost it is going to use.

Comment: Earlier I said that I had this working on my previous server but I'm not sure anymore if the www.domain.com actually worked there. That project is an api and I use it only through the subdomain interface.domain.com. However I plan to add also a web UI for the project. And then I would need to www.domain.com to work and not redirecting to the first site in the server.

Answer (score 5):

Do *not* mix IP:port and *:port definitions in your `<VirtualHost>` tags unless you are a very experienced Apache administrator and know exactly what you are doing.

Any domain that resolves to `1.2.3.4` (in you example) will be served by your one bound to 1.2.3.4:80 no matter which host name used.

If the server names and server alaises in your *:80 virtual host *do not* resolve to 1.2.3.4 then something else is wrong. If they do resolve to this IP, simply change you `<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>` to `<Virtualhost *:80>`

Additional comment: If you only have 1 IP on your server, only use the *:port version, it will avoid confusion

More comments:
Part of the problem may be the way you are sanitising all the domain names. this *must* be done consistently otherwise our efforts will be in vain. The way apache decides which server to send a request to is as follows. This just simply works, any *bug* in this process could never survive even the most basic of testing for an Apache release:

- If the connection is to a particular IP address and apache has a single matching `<VirtualHost>` tag for that ip/port then that virtual host will receive the request
- If not, apache looks at the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives for any `<VirtualHost>` that matches the IP/port the connection came in on and matches the `HTTP Host` header that came with the request. The first `<VirtualHost>` in the output of `apachectl -S` that matches will be the one to receive the request.
- If no match is found then the default virtual host for that IP/port receives the request. This is the first virtual hjost listed in the output of `apachectl -S` for a particular ip/port combination.

Remember the *IP* could just be `*`.

Comment: I have multiple ip addresses for the server. The DNS for domain.com is pointing to another ip that the server is listening. And the DNS for domainfirst.com is pointing to the 1.2.3.4

Comment: I tried to explicitly define the ip for the domain.com also. But it didn't change anything. Earlier I had all virtual hosts defined without IP addresses.

Comment: Then either some else is wrong or one of your assumptions is. Does www.domain.com resolve to the same IP as domain.com? Also can you clarify exactly which virtual hosts work and which do not?

Comment: `dig www.domainfirst.com` shows A record pointing to 1.2.3.4 and `dig www.domain.com` shows A record pointing to 1.2.3.5. Both IP's are listened by the server. `dig interface.domain.com`is also pointing to 1.2.3.5.

Comment: @Mika Maybe some routing / NAT problem? Do you port forward via iptables or something like that?

Comment: @Lenniey No, I don't have forwards in iptables, just allow and deny. I noticed that for plain `domain.com` I had set a url forward to `http://www.domain.com` in the DNS. I changed that to have an A record with the ip address 1.2.3.5. Need to wait an hour for that to take effect. Though, I cannot see how that could solve it.

Comment: Explicitly clear your browser cache and check the hosts file on the machine your browser is running from. Also check using a command line tool.

Comment: @Mika If you point your browser directly to the IP-address:port, what comes up, if anything at all?

Comment: @Lenniey The domain.com application server is running in port 8501 and pointing browser to `http://1.2.3.5:8501` opens the correct page.

Comment: Port 8501? Your apache config listens on port 80? EDIT: forget it, I can't read...sorry

Comment: @Mika I think he meant going via apache ... I've added some comments to my initial reply to try to explain some things

Comment: @Unbeliever Does Apache log the `HTTP Host` header somewhere so that I could check what string it is using when trying to find a match from the ServerName and ServerAlias?

Comment: @Mika http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html %{headername}i %{Host}i

Comment: I added `CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined` and `LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined` into apache2.conf. When I request www.domain.com the log shows `www.domainfirst.com:443 my.ip.address.47 - - [18/Nov/2016:11:45:47 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11068 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0`. The Host is `-`. I guess this log entry is written after the ServerName lookup.

Comment: Try `%{VARNAME}e`, as described in the doc: _If you're interested in what the request header was prior to when most modules would have modified it, use mod_setenvif to copy the header into an internal environment variable and log that value with the %{VARNAME}e described above._

Comment: the doc says "use mod_setenvif to copy the header into an internal environment variable and log that value with the %{VARNAME}e described above". So do I need to manually set the env variable in apache2.conf and then use it in the LogFormat?

Comment: OK. It is something about my browser. I tried from my phone and then it opens the correct page. Thanks @Lenniey and Unbeliever.

Comment: Using google chrome by any chance? It's notorious for caching stuff like that...